# Delphi need to free/shrink string?

Tags: string, delphi, memory-management

In this example, in a server service (live 24/24 hours), do I need to free/shrink `aBaz` for free clean/memory?

```
function foo(const aBar : string) : boolean;
var
    aBaz : string;
begin
    aBaz := 'very very long string';

    Result := (aBar = aBaz);

    aBaz := ''; // shrink `aBaz` for free memory
end;
```

**Update**

1. string var in a class is already free by class destroy or I need to shrink??

Eg.:

```
class Foo = class
   FBar : string;
   public
      constructor Create; overload;
      destructor  Destroy; reintroduce;
 end;

  constructor Foo.Create(const ABar : string);
  begin
      FBar := ABar;
  end;

  destructor Foo.Destroy;
  begin
      FBar := ''; // destructor already free memory or I need to shrink?
  end;
```

2. in a service (live 24/24 hours) when the run-time library frees the memory?

Comment: Your example above is obviously contrived to the point that the question is absurd.  Do you want to revise this question? How are you loading your strings and are they under 30K or are they several megabytes in length? Is the string really the problem or do you have an unbounded collection of objects or records each containing a large string field value?

Comment: @WarrenP string is up 30K (less or more 50K). I want only understand how delphy manage memory...

Comment: Unless your memory usage is unbounded, there is no reason to manage string memory explicitly. Typically the only management for string memory would be to put these large strings inside a class, and free the instance when you don't need it. But if you do, then you do.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

No, there is no need to free or shrink your string. Two reasons:

1. This particular string is a *string literal*. It's not allocated on the heap. The compiler includes a literal copy of that string in your EXE, and when you assign it to `aBaz`, the variable refers directly to that read-only memory in your EXE file. Nothing gets allocated, so there's nothing to free.
2. Strings in general are subject to automatic reference counting. When a string variable goes out of scope (which is what happens to `aBaz` when you reach the `end` keyword in this function), the string that the variable refers to has its reference count decremented. If the resulting count is zero, then the run-time library frees the memory associated with the string.

   The compiler inserts reference-managing code automatically. You don't need to do anything with it.

Comment: AFAIR string assignment from a constant MAY allocate a copy of the string on the heap, if aBaz is not a local variable. It will call UStrAsg instead of UStrLAsg. It is done so since the constant may come from a package, which may be unloaded from memory at any time. There is no performance cost in the OP case (where aBaz is local), but it would do memory allocation if aBaz is not local.

Comment: perfect! i have another question (see question update). if I understand, I do not have to do anything...

Comment: but in a service (live 24/24 hours) when the run-time library frees the memory?

Comment: @ar099968, as stated in this answer, strings are ref-counted and automatically managed by the compiler. When the variable goes out of scope, it is finalized without user intervention.

Answer (score 5):

No, you don't need to free strings on your own. Strings are managed automatically.

`aBaz` will be automatically *freed* when `foo` has finished. The string value will be removed from memory in case there is no other string variable containing the same value.